# Loading 5 strings into an array and printing them (MIPS)

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips, qtspim

I'm trying to load 5 strings into an array and then print them out. For some reason way beyond me, it's giving me errors every time it tries to print the elements. I think it could be something to do with the way I'm indexing but when comparing it to various tutorials on the internet, it seems like it should be right. I'm new to MIPS and still getting the hang of it, so go easy on me if its something stupid I'm missing. Thanks a bunch.

My code is below:

```
    # Data Section
    .data

Input:      .asciiz     "Enter a series of 5 formulae:\n"
Output:     .asciiz     "The values are:\n"
NL:     .asciiz     "\n"
myArray:    .space      40
insert1:    .space       4  # makes space in memory (8 bytes) for a word 
with address insert1                    
insert2:    .space       4                  
insert3:    .space       4                  
insert4:    .space       4                  
insert5:    .space       4  

    # Text Section
    .text

main:

    la $a0, Input    # Prints out Input
    li $v0, 4    # sets $v0 to 4 (print code)
    syscall     

    la $a0, insert1
    la $a1, insert1
    li $v0, 8
    move $s0, $a0       
    syscall

    la $a0, insert2
    la $a1, insert2   
    li $v0, 8
    move $s1, $a0           
    syscall 

    la $a0, insert3 
    la $a1, insert3       
    li $v0, 8   
    move $s2, $a0       
    syscall 

    la $a0, insert4   
    la $a1, insert4
    li $v0, 8   
    move $s3, $a0       
    syscall 

    la $a0, insert5  
    la $a1, insert5  
    li $v0, 8   
    move $s4, $a0       
    syscall     

    # Index/Offset = $t0
    li $t0, 0

    sw $s0, myArray($t0)
       addi $t0, $t0, 4
    sw $s1, myArray($t0)
       addi $t0, $t0, 4
   sw $s2, myArray($t0)
       addi $t0, $t0, 4
   sw $s3, myArray($t0)
       addi $t0, $t0, 4
   sw $s4, myArray($t0)

   # Clear $t0 to 0
   li $t0, 0


while:

    beq $t0, 20, quit


    lw $t1, myArray($t0)
    addi $t0, $t0, 4

    #prints element
    li $v0, 1
    move $a0, $t1
    syscall

    #prints new line
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, NL
    syscall

    j while


quit:

    # Exits Program
    li $v0, 10 
    syscall
```

Comment: Reading and writing words from/to memory requires the address to be word-aligned (a multiple of 4). Use `.align 2` to ensure that `myArray` is word-align.

Comment: Thanks, it actually did work. stupid mistake on my part.